# Dynamically add !important to all CSS properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I dynamically add `!important` for all CSS properties?

For example in my `<head></head>` section I have:

```
<style>
    .text-center {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .text-left {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .main-container {
        border: 3px solid yellow;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        margin: 3px;
    }    
</style>
```

I need:

```
<style>
    .text-center {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    .text-left {
        text-align: left !important;
    }
    .main-container {
        border: 3px solid yellow !important;
        padding: 10px 5px !important;
        margin: 3px !important;
    }    
</style>
```

I tried to use [Window.getComputedStyle()](http://Window.getComputedStyle()), but I must provide to this method the element for which I want to get the computed style. In my case I can't provide these elements.

Comment: No! No! No!.... ***Never, ever do this!***

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're **really** trying to achieve.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I need some JS function that can get all the styles from attribute `<style></style>` in `<head></head>` section and add to all CSS rules `!important`. I have some page and there are a lot of CSS in `<style></style>`. I must add to all these rules `!important`. I hope you understand me.

Comment: I know WHAT you want...and I'm saying it's not a good idea. Tell us WHY you need to do this.

Comment: I'd like to create some "Add extra CSS" functionality with live preview, like jsbin or plunker. I need to add this extra CSS to some "live" widget, that has its own CSS rules with `!important`. That styles are injected with JS when page loads. So, when user wants to add his own CSS, he writes them into `textarea` and I "listen" it. And then I add `<style></style>` with user's input to the `<head></head>` section. But it won't be worked, because previous CSS rules are with important. So, the user must add `!important` to his custom CSS rules or I instead of him (on the front-end side).

Comment: Ugh.....that sound horrible.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I know... But i must overwrite widget's CSS with user's custom CSS. And it must work dynamically. I add user's custom CSS after widget's CSS, but it won't work, because all the rules in widget CSS are with important... I can create some "hint" for my users, that they need use `!important`, but I don't want to make them do it. I want to add `!important` by myself.

Comment: Make sure you learn about css priorities, There is no need for you to put important at all. If the user css is read last then it will take priority, also if a css rule is specified with lot of selectors it takes priority EG 'div.span.red' takes priority over 'div.red'

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue with printing (with css styling) in Chrome and Firefox..
even adding **-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact!important;** didnt work in my case

until i figured out that the style need to have **!important** attribute. When working with WYSWYG Editor, this could be a problem for printing. So I need to add !important to every css style attribute found in every element.

Here's how I solved it using jQuery

```
//add !important rule to every style found in each element
//so the browser print render the color/style also
var el = $('.content *');

if (el.length) {
    el.each(function(item) {
        var _this = $(this);
        var attr = _this.attr('style');
        var style = '';
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
            if (attr.split(';').length) {
                attr.split(';').forEach(function(item) {
                    if (item.trim() != '') {
                        style += item.trim() + '!important;-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact!important;';
                    }
                });

                _this.attr('style', style);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the result in Printing Preview before and After adding the Code Hack

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem with pandas DataFrame Styler. It generated a `<style>` tag element with all the styling info. But the styling is overridden by linked css files.

So my solution is to replace all `;` with `!important;` using JavaScript

CSS:

```
<style  type="text/css" >
#T_195822c0_1b0f_11e9_93d2_42010a8a0003row10_col4 {
        background-color:  yellow;
    }    #T_195822c0_1b0f_11e9_93d2_42010a8a0003row73_col5 {
        background-color:  yellow;
    }    #T_195822c0_1b0f_11e9_93d2_42010a8a0003row100_col2 {
        background-color:  yellow;
    }</style>
```

Javascript:

```
var st = document.getElementsByTagName("STYLE")[0];
st.innerHTML = st.innerHTML.replace(/yellow;/g,'yellow !important;')
```

You can adapt replace rules to your need.